# looping query SPARQL in Python

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I have a task for looping a query SPARQL for each term. But i have no idea to process in a code, especially Python. I use the RDFlib for Python and my codes show below:

```
for joined in removed:
print (joined)
```

output:

```
sistem
pakar
diagnosis
penyakit
tht
balita
metode
certainty
factor
```

those terms have through text pre-processing. And after that i want to query those terms but in looping way. the query format:

```
qres = g.query(
"""SELECT ?z 
    WHERE {?x rdfs:label ?z .               
          FILTER CONTAINS (LCASE(str(?z)), LCASE ('THE_TERM')) .    
    }
    LIMIT 100""")
```

i am new to Python, so is there any way to process query for each term consecutively? or should i use `switch` and `case` function? please advise me, thank you.

Comment: you have a loop and just do String inline, where is the problem? Here we go, depending on your Python version you have multiple options: https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html

Comment: also, you're aware that you could do this in a single SPARQL query? Just use `VALUES` clause

Answer (score -1):

There is no switch in Python!

See the documentation for rdflib regarding looping through query results here: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html

In short:

```
g = Graph()
# do something to load the graph with data

q = g.query("""SOME SPARQL QUERY""")
for r in g.query():
    print(r)
    # or
    print(r['x'])  # if you returned a variable ?x in your SPARQL query
```